# Euca 5.0 No Node Controllers

Tags: eucalyptus

I've used the ansible install to run all services on a single host and have two separate physical node controllers.

Everything installed fine and all of my services are green. But I don't think image workers are launching to do my first image uploads.  As I'm trying to troubleshoot I see that no node controllers are reported by:

`euserv-describe-node-controllers`

It doesn't return an error just blank output. I've unregistered and re-registered the two node controllers and copied the CLC admin keys with no errors but still can't see output from that command.  cloud-output and the various nc log files seem to show successful startup.

I've switched to ImagingServiceAdministrator to look for imaging worker instances with this and got blank output which was what started me looking at NC's:

```
euca-describe-instances --filter tag-value=euca-internal-imaging-workers
```

Answer (score 0):

The imaging service is not required for installing instance-store images, e.g.:

```
python <(curl -Ls https://eucalyptus.cloud/images)
```

or (on an ansible deployed cloud):

```
eucalyptus-images --size 1
```

To check on the status of node controllers in a deployment you will need to have cloud administrator credentials. You can check this using:

```
euare-getcallerid
euare-accountlist
```

and verifying that the `eucalyptus` account is being used.

Node controllers are managed via a cluster controller so you should check the status for both:

```
euserv-describe-services -a --filter service-type=cluster
euserv-describe-services -a --filter service-type=node
```

this differs from `euserv-describe-node-controllers` as it does not include information on running instances.

If there are any issues you can check for service events:

```
euserv-describe-events
```

and look at the logs (/var/log/eucalyptus/...) to further investigate.

Check that the IP addresses you registered node controllers using are the ones that the node controllers are listening on (`NC_ADDR` in */etc/eucalyptus//eucalyptus.conf*)

If using firewalld restart/reload the configuration after deployment to ensure running with the latest settings.

Comment: I think I'm halfway there. I thought the ansible installer firewalld settings would also take care to allow the network between NC and CC but it did not. Whats strange is now that I've opened up the iptables appropriately I can still only see one node. The two I'm testing with had identical ansible output without error and I can't see any config differences on them.

Comment: Another weird network bit/clue that I can't seem to understand is there is no firewall at all running on my CLC,UFS,CC,SC server but I can't reach a guest public IP running on the node that I do have connected. A traceroute shows an end-user client on my network reaching my router and then (via static route) reaching my CLC,UFS,CC,SC but that server instead of acting as a gateway returns the traffic to my router (via its default route I presume.) Did I miss a step to add a route on the CLC,UFS server? I enabled ipv4 forwarding in sysctl.conf as a guess but it didn't help. I'm in VPCMIDO mode